# Nokogiri XML Creating field names help needed - Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to create an XML doc using the specification provided to me by a partner and I am having some issues creating the XML field names as specified. We generally create the field names so the output appears like the example below.

```
def build_xml(output_rows)
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'utf-8') do |xml|     
xml.BATCH{
  xml.HEADER{
      xml.CBPosterEmail ("test@foo.com")
      xml.CBPosterPassword ('123456')
      xml.CBReplace ('Yes')
      xml.CBReplyTo ('replytome@foo.com')
  } #xml HEADER


<Header>
<CBEmail>test@foo.com</CBEmail>
<CBPosterPassword>123456</CBPosterPassword>
<CBReplace>Yes</CBReplace>
<CBReplyTo>replytome@foo.com</CBReplyTo>
</Header>
```

I need to have the field names appear in the output as the example below:

```
<Header>
<Field name="CBPosterEmail" value="test@foo.com" />
<Field name="CBPosterPassword" value="123456" />
<Field name=”CbReplace” value=”Yes”>
<Field name=”CBReplyTo” value=”replytome@foo.com”>
</Header>
```

I am getting an error when I try to add the Field name=" and the value= piece. I am a complete novice with Nokogiri so please go easy on me if I sound like a complete idiot. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code sample isn't correct syntax. Please replace it with something that will at least run.

Comment: Also, don't apologize at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'utf-8') do |xml|
xml.batch {
  xml.header {
    xml.field(:name => "CBPosterEmail", :value => "test@foo.com")
    xml.field(:name => "CBPosterPassword", :value => "123456")
    xml.field(:name => "CBReplace", :value => "Yes")
    xml.field(:name => "CBReplyTo", :value => "replytome@foo.com")
  }
}
end
puts builder.to_xml

=> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<batch>
  <header>
    <field name="CBPosterEmail" value="test@foo.com"/>
    <field name="CBPosterPassword" value="123456"/>
    <field name="CBReplace" value="Yes"/>
    <field name="CBReplyTo" value="replytome@foo.com"/>
  </header>
</batch>
```

Answer (score 2):

See the "[Tag attributes](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html)" section of Nokogiri's Builder documentation.

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'utf-8') do |xml|     
  xml.BATCH{
    xml.HEADER{
      xml.Field( name: 'CBPosterEmail',    value: 'test@foo.com'      )
      xml.Field( name: 'CBPosterPassword', value: '123456'            )
      xml.Field( name: 'CBReplace',        value: 'Yes'               )
      xml.Field( name: 'CBReplyTo',        value: 'replytome@foo.com' )
    }
  }
end

puts builder.to_xml
```

Which results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BATCH>
  <HEADER>
    <Field name="CBPosterEmail" value="test@foo.com"/>
    <Field name="CBPosterPassword" value="123456"/>
    <Field name="CBReplace" value="Yes"/>
    <Field name="CBReplyTo" value="replytome@foo.com"/>
  </HEADER>
</BATCH>
```

The sample code shows you're trying to add a `<BATCH>` tag, but the desired output sample doesn't show it. If the output sample is correct this will generate that:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'utf-8') do |xml|     
  xml.HEADER{
    xml.Field( name: 'CBPosterEmail',    value: 'test@foo.com'      )
    xml.Field( name: 'CBPosterPassword', value: '123456'            )
    xml.Field( name: 'CBReplace',        value: 'Yes'               )
    xml.Field( name: 'CBReplyTo',        value: 'replytome@foo.com' )
  }
end
```

Which results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HEADER>
  <Field name="CBPosterEmail" value="test@foo.com"/>
  <Field name="CBPosterPassword" value="123456"/>
  <Field name="CBReplace" value="Yes"/>
  <Field name="CBReplyTo" value="replytome@foo.com"/>
</HEADER>
```

Comment: Thanks you for the help and the recommendation regarding the Tag attributes.